# hide and show intermittent uilabel and uinavigation title?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

Hello to all people!!

I need to made one uilabel thats shows and hide intermittently likes information message in the main view...

I need the same in the title of the navigation bar... Is this possible?

any suggestions please...

Answer (score 7):

Sure.

Supposing you have:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel * myLabel;
```

You can easily:

```
[self.myLabel setHidden:YES];
```

or

```
self.myLabel.hidden = YES;
```

or

```
[self.myLabel setHidden:NO];
```

or

```
self.myLabel.hidden = NO;
```

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html

Comment: @Jose, By the way - Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you could be so kind as to mark proposed answers (such as mine) as correct (by selecting the checkmark to the left of the proposed answer), that would be wonderful. Thanks!

Comment: thanks for your answer but is possible that i dont explain very well my question... i need to show this intermittent uilabel until the user no modify the configuration and turn on the application... in others words i need to show and hide the information message until the user interaction...

Comment: OK. So once "the user interaction" `self.myLabel.hidden = YES;` Seems straight-forward to me. Unless you question is about something completely different - which you didn't ask in your post.

Comment: Sorry if I dont explain very clear, but my english in not so good...I need to show the label and hide the label all the time until the user do something... I know that you can show the label with self.label.hidden=no; and quit the label with self.label.hidden=yes; but i need to do this all the time when the view will appears...

Comment: `but i need to do this all the time when the view will appears.` You've lost me my friend. All you've asked about is `hide and show intermittent uilabel` I've answered that question. Did you have another question? If so, what is it? How do you expect me to know what the problem you're having with `but i need to do this all the time when the view will appears.` is, unless you tell me?

Comment: Ok... My application has one button thats is enable when one configuration switch is on and the button is hidden when the switch is of... When the button is hidden i want to show an alert message intermittently (show/hide) notifying that the app is out of service or something like that and when the user go to the configuration and turn on the switch the button appears and the intermittent (show/hide) alert message disappear...  I don't know if with one nstimer i can do that the alert message remains in the state "intermittent" or what is the method for to made that